# Card Game Simulation list.remove

Tags: class, python-3.x, simulation

I am following a pretty good python book and it teaches you how to create a simulation for some card games. As you can see below I have created a class "Card", for indexes all possible combinations of cards in a deck. Then I created a class "Deck", which makes the deck from the combinations of cards in "Card". My question is this, I'm trying to simulate someone taking a card from the decl, but can't get the last class function removeCard to work, and I'm not quite sure why. Can someone help me understand my problem and how to correct it? Thanks.

```
class Card:
def __init__(self, suit = 0, rank = 2):
    Card.suit = suit
    Card.rank = rank
#Two class attributes that are helpful in determining suit/rank
ranklist = ['narf', 'Ace', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', \
'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
suitlist = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
def __repr__(self):
    return (self.ranklist[self.rank] + " of " + self.suitlist[self.suit])


class Deck:
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []
    for suit in range(4):
        for rank in range(1,13):
            x = Card()
            x.rank = rank
            x.suit = suit 
            self.cards.append(x)
def printDeck(self):
    for card in self.cards:
        print(card)

def removeCard(self, card):
        if card in self.cards:
            self.cards.remove(card)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: _"but can't get the last class function removeCard to work."_ Could you provide complete, runnable code that demonstrates how you create the deck, remove a card, and show the results? Also, can you double check that your code was formatted properly in the post? I'm getting an `IndentationError` when I try to run it.

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a typo in your Card's `__init__` function. you should be assigning attributes to `self`, not `Card`.

Second, 
I'm guessing you're doing something like:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit = 0, rank = 2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    #Two class attributes that are helpful in determining suit/rank
    ranklist = ['narf', 'Ace', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', \
    'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    suitlist = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.ranklist[self.rank] + " of " + self.suitlist[self.suit])


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1,13):
                x = Card()
                x.rank = rank
                x.suit = suit 
                self.cards.append(x)
    def printDeck(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            print(card)

    def removeCard(self, card):
            if card in self.cards:
                self.cards.remove(card)
                return True
            else:
                return False

d = Deck()
print "The deck has {} cards.".format(len(d.cards))
card = Card(1,1)
print "Removing the {}.".format(card)
d.removeCard(card)
print "The deck has {} cards.".format(len(d.cards))
```

And you expect the output to be:

```
The deck has 48 cards.
Removing the Ace of Diamonds.
The deck has 47 cards.
```

But you actually get:

```
The deck has 48 cards.
Removing the Ace of Diamonds.
The deck has 48 cards.
```

Your `removeCard` method is failing because, by default, objects in python are equal only if their ids are equal. Example:

```
>>> a = Card(1,1)
>>> b = Card(1,1)

>>> a == a
True
>>> id(a) == id(a)
True

>>> a == b
False
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
```

Even though both a and b are created with `Card(1,1)`, they aren't equal. When you try `if card in self.cards:`, Python asks, does self.cards contain a card with this exact id? And in the case of my first code snippet, it replies `False`.

You can override this default behavior by specifying your own `__eq__` in the `Card` class.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit = 0, rank = 2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    #Two class attributes that are helpful in determining suit/rank
    ranklist = ['narf', 'Ace', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', \
    'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    suitlist = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Card): return False
        return self.suit == other.suit and self.rank == other.rank
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.ranklist[self.rank] + " of " + self.suitlist[self.suit])
```

Now `in` and `remove` will behave properly, and remove your card as desired.

```
The deck has 48 cards.
Removing the Ace of Diamonds.
The deck has 47 cards.
```

Comment: Your answer is correct and comprehensive! Great work. @srhoades28: consider instead shuffling your Deck using `import random; random.shuffle(self.cards)` at the end of your `Deck.__init__`, then simply tying your `removeCard` function into a `drawCard` function using `self.cards.pop()`. It's generally not otherwise necessary to remove a given card from a real-world deck of cards.

Comment: Can't tell you how long I worked on this. Great advice!